# Read Committed Data Without Waiting in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible in SQL Server to read committed data with NoWait when the row is already locked for update?

I created a table named "Tbl"

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tbl](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Detail] [varchar](50) NULL)
```

Inserted Few Rows.

```
insert into Tbl(Detail) values ('1D')
insert into Tbl(Detail) values ('2D')
insert into Tbl(Detail) values ('3D')
insert into Tbl(Detail) values ('4D')
```

Now, I have set implicit transactions to true in SSMS. (Tools -> Options -> SQL Server -> ANSI.

Then, In one session(Opened New Query Window) executed update statement, Which should put an Exclusive Lock on the row.

```
UPDATE dbo.tbl  SET Detail = '9D' where Id = 1
```

Now, In another session I want to select committed rows. If I execute,

`SELECT * FROM dbo.tbl with(READCOMMITTED,NOWAIT)` , It throws exception(Lock Request Timeout Period Exceed)

It's probably trying to apply Shared Lock on the row where another session already applied Exclusive Lock. Thus getting exception.

Now, This is a common scenario where One Transaction is taking long time to update huge rows. I should be able to see committed data in another session without waiting.

What type of HINT is required to achieve this in SQL Server?

Comment: Voting to migrate to DBA.StackExchange

Comment: I think you want [`READPAST`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx)

Comment: @TI READPAST won't do it, it completely skips dirty records.  I don't think there is any way.

Answer (score 8):

This is only available in form of `SNAPSHOT` isolation (or read-committed-snapshot mode). You need to enable it on the database first.

Running a transaction under `SNAPSHOT` isolation means that neither does it take locks nor does it wait for them. The tran sees a point-in-time snapshot of the database.

Answer (score 3):

That's not the way locking works. If the engine decides that it would be more efficient to escalate to page or table lock, then you're not going to read the committed data until the lock is released.

The best thing I can think of is to enable read committed snapshot isolation on the database. What this does is that it will get you the rows as they stand when the statement starts.

[I recently had to learn about this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/44559/4490)